# Where is `php-fpm' on OS X?

Tags: macos, nginx, php

Where is the `php-fpm` binary on Mac OS 10.6 (PHP 5.3.26)?

Since PHP-FPM was added in PHP 5.3.3, my machine should have php-fpm somewhere, although I can't find it under `/usr`.

Comment: Was your php version packaged with it?...

Comment: @Ohgodwhy How could it not be? I was under the impression it was part of the default install, reading: http://php-fpm.org/.

Comment: did you install php with brew? i can try to recreate

Comment: Save yourself a lot of grief and install things like PHP in OSX via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no, this is the built-in PHP; part of Mac OS 10.6.8

Comment: Then that's why. You should instead follow @ceejayoz's advice

Comment: @Ohgodwhy My question is about the built-in PHP, not a seperately compiled version. I to assume that Apple managed to build PHP without the `php-fpm` module or is it just hiding somewhere?

Comment: @Hawken Per the PHP docs, FPM is only included if you compile with the `--enable-fpm` flag. OSX comes with Apache+mod_php instead.

Comment: Ah, thank you. If you put that as an answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: I think @Ceejayoz is right. See my another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25100138/199593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the PHP bundled with your system, then you already have it. If you run `php -i` you should get what would normally be the output of `phpinfo()` within a script. Up at the top in a long list of directives you should see that `php-fpm` is already bundled with `php` with the `--enable-fpm` directive.

So to answer your question, you can find both by typing:

```
whereis php
```