# Problems compile phalcon on osx 10.9

Tags: php, macos, phalcon

Trying to follow instruction from documentation:

running

```
$ sudo ./install
```

and get this:

```
gcc -I. -I/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/include -I/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/main -I/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits -I/usr/local/php5/include/php -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/main -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/ext/date/lib -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2 -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden -c /Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:108409:21: error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c: In function ‘phalcon_translate_adapter_gettext_read_dimension’:
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:108425: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘gettext’
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c: In function ‘phalcon_translate_adapter_gettext_has_dimension’:
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:108441: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘gettext’
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c: In function ‘zim_Phalcon_Translate_Adapter_Gettext_query’:
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:108553: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘gettext’
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:108555: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘dgettext’
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c: In function ‘zim_Phalcon_Translate_Adapter_Gettext_exists’:
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:108590: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘gettext’
/Users/honky/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:108592: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘dgettext’
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1
```

Any guess?

Answer (score 3):

Mac os x ships with PHP 5.x preinstalled for a long time but installing not pre-installed  extensions and solving library dependencies steals lot of free time and requires extra effort, getting lost in un-relevant google results. My experience has showed me that, the hard way. I strongly recommend using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) on Mac OS X to eliminate really unnecessary pains like this.

After you have successfully installed Homebrew, having **Phalcon** extension (and thousands of other open source libs/tools/apps) as simple as this:

```
$ brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
$ brew install php55-phalcon
```

When you need another extension or library, just type:

```
$ brew search <whatever>
```

To learn more about a formula or installing options:

```
$ brew info <whatever>
```

**Note:** Homebrew requires installing [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). Make sure that Xcode is installed on your mac before brewing. If something went wrong, use `brew doctor` command to get an idea about what's happening.