# Create Zend Framework Project in AMPPS (Mac)

Tags: php, zend-framework2, ampps

I'm using AMPPS 2.9 and installed the Zend Framework 2.3.5 from the AMPPS menu. I'd like to create a new project based on the framework. I tried the very first command on the first method at [Zend Installation Instructions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/ref/installation.html), pointing it to the AMPPS php, but I git this error. I have not been able to find AMPPS-specific create project instructions. I think the problem is my terminal session is based on my host Mac, not the AMPPS environment. Has anyone created a Zend project under AMPPS?

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | /Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/php --
#!/usr/bin/env php

Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.

Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The ctype extension is missing.

Install it or recompile php without --disable-ctype
```

Comment: are you alredy installed xcode?

Comment: For mac os x, homebrew is best & painless way to go for development. You may want to check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095942/problems-compile-phalcon-on-osx-10-9/25100138#25100138

Comment: @foozy-- I looked at this and it looks interesting. But I'd prefer to have a developer environment isolated from my "personal production" use of my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Zend AMPPS has stored in their repository for AMPPS for users to install. AMPPS is really a MAMP(mac) or WAMP/XAMPP(windows). Its basically a LAMP stack and a web server management tool for local development (not serving websites).

I would install Zend Frameworks from the Zend website (maybe look into zend Optimizer also). By default your php installation is barebone, you'll need to install `php-gd, php-mysql, php-curl, php-crypt or mcrypt` manually. If you're on linux you can issue > `apt-get/ or yum install php5-ctype` and if you're on a mac you can easily use port > `sudo port install php5-curl` and do that for all the missing extensions manually.

My suggestion would be to install ZF latest from ZF website and install the required extensions required by ZF or your ZF app.

Comment: @unixmiah-- You overlooked much in my question. I mentioned the version of Zend Framework that comes with AMPPS 2.9. It is version 2.3.5. And I already had the framework installed. Your last suggestion is so vague, it was really not helpful. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install the Zend 2 Framework Skeleton Application as follows.

1. Download it from [github](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) using the Download ZIP button on the page.
2. Unzip it and move/rename top-level folder to desired location/name.
3. Open a terminal window and cd to new folder.
4. Do a "php composer.phar self-update".
5. Do a "php composer.phar install".
6. From the AMPPS home page, choose Add New Domain and point the path to your new folder location appended with /public. For example, "//public".
7. In a browser, navigate to the new domain and you should see the "Welcome to Zend Framework 2" skeleton application page.